# Каким образом получить нужный массив для js?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Здравствуйте. В js есть такая переменная, которая содержит:

```
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp"
 ];
```

Я же пытаюсь сделать чтобы значения в этой переменной брались из базы данных mysql.

Для этого я делаю конструкцию вида:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[] = "Parametr 1";
$arr[] = "Parametr 2";
$arr[] = "Parametr 1";
```

И в js в эту функцию подставляю этот массив:

```
availableTags = ['<?php echo $arr;?>'];
```

Но в итоге не работает.
Работает если только указывать конкретный номер объекта: `availableTags = ['<?php echo $arr[1];?>'];`

Но в таком случае и объект один получается.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: и далее перебераешь массив в JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходя из вашего решения:

```
availableTags = ['<?php echo implode('\',\'',$arr);?>'];
```

Исходя из здравого смысла:

```
availableTags = <?php=json_encode($arr); ?>;
```

Comment: точно! замечательно. спасибо за помощь.